# Javascript array format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two javascript array

```
let a=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
let b=[{count:35, name:'test', age:12}, {count:45 name:'test2', age:9}];
```

and two array push into i need final Array format is

```
[{count:35,name:'test', age,12, id:1} , {count:35, name:'test', age:12,id:2},{count:35, name:'test', age:12,id:3},{count:45,name:'test', age,9, id:1} , {count:45, name:'test', age:9,id:2},{count:45, name:'test', age:9,id:3} ]
```

And i trying

```
for ( var index=0; index<b.length; index++ ) {
    
    for ( var j=0; j<a.length; j++ ) {

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a[j])) {
             //if(j==index)
               b[index][key]=value;
               k[j]=b[index];

        }
        console.log( b[index]);
        c.push(b[index]);
        
    }


}
console.log(c);
```

and it shows final value is
[image]

please any body help to fix the problem

Comment: I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation, is essentially updating the same b objects over and over, x number of times, changing their IDs each time through, ending at 3.

You need to "clone" the objects, so they are separate objects, like so:

```
  let p = []; // Permutations
  
  let a = [{id:1},{id:2}]; // Renditions...
  // Presets...
  let b = [{count:35, name:'test', age:12}, {count:45, name:'test2', age:9}];
  
  // for each Rendition
  a.forEach(function(a) {
     // for each Preset
     b.forEach(function(b){
         // generate Permutation and Clone, object of b with additional id prop
         p.push(Object.assign({id: a.id}, b)); // <-- Cloned here...
     });
  });

   console.log(p)
```

for the sake of clarity, you might consider changing the `id` prop to `grouping` or `group` or `group_id`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
let a=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
let b=[{count:35, name:'test', age:12}, {count:45, name:'test2', age:9}];

let m = b.flatMap(itemB => a.map(itemA => ({...itemB, ...itemA })))

console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. The thing is that you are mutating the same **b** object every iteration, that's why in the end you get id = 3 for every element. You can use a deep copy of b in each cycle, and the error should be gone.

Here's one way to deep clone, not the most efficient but it is very clear:

```
        const bCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b[index]));

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a[j])) {
             //if(j==index)
               bCopy[key]=value;
               k[j]=bCopy;   // what's this for?

        }
        console.log(bCopy);
        c.push(bCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce `b` and for each item `b1`, reduce `a`. When reducing `a`, just assign both `b1` and `a1` to a new object.

```js
const expectedValue = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(
  document.getElementById('expected').value))

let a = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
]

let b = [
  { count: 35, name: 'test',  age: 12 },
  { count: 45, name: 'test2', age: 9  }
]

let c = b.reduce((res, b1) =>
  a.reduce((res1, a1) =>
    [...res1, Object.assign({}, b1, a1)], res), [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(c) === expectedValue)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }

#expected { display: none; }
```

```html
<textarea id="expected">
[
  { "count": 35, "name": "test",  "age": 12, "id": 1 },
  { "count": 35, "name": "test",  "age": 12, "id": 2 },
  { "count": 35, "name": "test",  "age": 12, "id": 3 },
  { "count": 45, "name": "test2", "age": 9,  "id": 1 },
  { "count": 45, "name": "test2", "age": 9,  "id": 2 },
  { "count": 45, "name": "test2", "age": 9,  "id": 3 }
]
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes.

```
    let a=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
    let b=[{count:35, name:'test', age:12}, {count:45, name:'test2', age:9}];
    let c=[];
    for ( var index=0; index<b.length; index++ ) {
        for ( var j=0; j<a.length; j++ ) {
         var obj=b[index];
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a[j])) {
                   obj[key]=value;
            }
            c.push(obj);
        }
    }
    console.log(c);
```